# JQuery toggle without inline CSS (slide left)

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, slidetoggle

I have a sidebar on my website which I hide on a click with.

```
$('#sidebar').toggle('slide', 'left', 300)
```

I also have a CSS style which hides this sidebar mobiles.

```
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}

/* if screen size gets wider than 768 */
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

However these 2 don't work together very well because `.toggle()` uses inline CSS. Is there any way to make `.toggle()` use an inline style? Or would there be a better solution to this.

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: `!important` in your css overrules inline css

Comment: Yes, but this always shows the sidebar even when I use .toggle() to hide it. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: When do you want it to show, and when do you want it hidden?

Comment: Default it's shown (so the #sidebar has a display: block). When you click on a link it's hidden, when you click on it again it's shown etc.

Comment: I reversed the media query and it works like this. Is this considered correct? `@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    #filter-content {
        display: none !important;
    }
}`

Comment: There's no real problem there (though you might want to change it to 767px for max-width), some purists would tell you that it breaks the 'mobile first'  principle, but unless you fancy rewriting jQuery.toggle() you do what you gotta.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with classes and toggle that class. Now it will work together because it doesnt matter if the sidebar is open.

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    display: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; 
    -moz-transition: all 1s; 
    transition: all 1s;
}
#sidebar.open {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

/* if screen size gets wider than 768 */
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Also when using animations to open something. Use transform for browser optimization.

jQuery:

```
$('#sidebar').toggleClass('open')
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have nearly gotten it working but the sidebar stays hidden when I put `display: none` on it. When this isn't on there it works but the div is not removed from the DOM.

Comment: Can you try display: block !important; ?

Comment: It works, but then the div isn't removed from the DOM (which I need). I realise this is a harder matter it seems.

Comment: If you mean removed, like delete the html. You cant do that with css. thats only possible with javascript/jquery. $('#sidebar').remove();

Comment: You can detect it the screensize by jquery and then delete it if that is what you want

Comment: Nono, the div just needs `display: none` active on it. Which is now not happening when the media query has `display: block !important`. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: This should work, just tested it my self.. Isnt there something else thats blocks the block? used !important before? Can you make a fiddle? Is your media query placed below your code? Does the media query work? Put background-color: green; on it and see if the query works.

Comment: Seems like the `display: flex` on my parent div might be causing this behaviour. https://jsfiddle.net/jzh1crto/ You can see that the 'sidebar' div is keeping it's space, while the space should be going away. And that happens when `display: none` is active on the sidebar.

Comment: Your code does work at my screen... is your screen even bigger then 768px?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I mean. I want the area I highlighted [here](http://i.imgur.com/s9EoVZL.jpg) to be gone when no content is being shown there. So that it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/ALcTEI3.jpg). Even when the screen is bigger than 768px!